# Copy Oracle Database 11g XE to FreeNAS storage

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a storage partition created by FreeNAS. In server 2012 machine, I map this storage to use for Oracle database 11g Express Edition.

But when I create new database in Oracle Database 11g Express Edition, I don't know how to specify location for it to store new database file in FreeNAS's storage.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to "create a new database"? With Oracle 11 that means you are trying to create a second instance and I don't think that is something you can do with Oracle XE

Comment: You do know that XE11g has a storage limit of 11GB ?

Comment: I knew it. But I still need to use it.

Comment: Using XE is fine but having a NAS for its storage strikes me as over-engineering.